# Decontaminate or contaminate

Tags: word-usage

We have a message on the noticeboard in our workplace. The message is to collect plastic bottle tops for some charity organisation (most likely another myth similar to the [Aluminium Tabs Myth](https://www.livestrong.com/article/196999-recycling-aluminum-tabs-vs-cans/), but it is not the point of this question).

I have a question about the usage of the word *decontaminate* in this sentence:

> Make sure all the tops are rinsed beforehand and ensure they do not have rubber or metal attached to the tops as these will only *decontaminate* the mix.

I believe that the person who made this note wanted us to prevent the mix from contamination by foreign material, so the metal and rubber should be removed. Thus, they should have used the word *contaminate*.

Am I right?

[image: Check the last sentence]

Comment: Yes, that's very probably a mistake. The context strongly suggests the author meant to say *contaminate*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of decontaminate instead of contaminate is almost certainly a mistake.

---

Purely in terms of grammar, the use of decontaminate *could* make sense if the instructions were meant to accomplish something *more than just* decontamination.

In other words:

> Make sure all the tops are **rinsed beforehand** and ensure they **do not have rubber or metal attached to the tops** as these will *only* decontaminate the mix. [The mix should be both decontaminated and **visible** from above.]

In this possible context, the use of rubber or metal attached to the milk bottle tops will prevent anybody from seeing the contents. So, this version of the sentence is saying be saying that while rinsing ensures decontamination, the use of rubber or metal tops doesn't allow for the further requirement of transparency.

However, while this is possible, it's much more likely that what's being expressed is that having rubber or metal attached to the milk bottle tops will cause the milk to become contaminated when it comes into contact with that material. So, in short, the opposite word should have been used.